# How to get last website modified date, not specific post in wordpress

Tags: wordpress

I would like to get last modification date of my overall website (not a specific post or page). Is there a query or something to get it?

Comment: You should ask this on the dedicated WordPress stack exchange site. I don't think WordPress has any such feature by the way. What would last modification be? The most recent date between post page media or an actual file on the server?

Comment: @DavidBrossard I was not aware of wordpress stack. I'll ask there.

Comment: Glad I could help. You can always cross-link

Comment: What i want is, display the last modified date of overall website. It can be post or page

Comment: I'm thinking this might require custom code

Comment: @DavidBrossard Hmm.. May need to write a custom query to sort posts by modified date and find date from results.